# Maintaining event order in log4j + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, log4j

I'm investigating MongoDB as a log repository. I've set up a basic MongoDB server, configured Log4j, and everything seems to work.

However:

- I'm aware that MongoDB writes are asynchronous (and I don't want to kill performance by making them synchronous)
- The timestamp in the log records appears to be accurate only to the millisecond
- My app logs more than once per millisecond
- I need to be able to see the sequence in which the events were logged

Is there a way I can get more granular timestamps?

Is there a way I can inject sequence numbers on the client side (short of having the client put them in the log message)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB inserts are sequential since write locks are process wide. As such you are guaranteed that MongoDB will return the log entries in the order it received them. Use sort({$natural:1}) to get them back in order.

Note that although writes are asynchronous they are ordered.

Comment: If you're logging to a sharded environment let me know. There are a few things to take into account in that case.